# Should the Jetpack Compose tags be normalised?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Jetpack Compose tags are in a bit of disarray.

1. Using [android-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose) always feels weird because I'm rarely targeting Android. But, sometimes it's still the right tag for me to use because what I'm doing is in the common code.
2. Meanwhile, the [compose-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-desktop) tag has the "compose" slug but not the "jetpack" slug, and same for [compose-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-web).

If it were me, I would probably try to normalise them like this:

- [jetpack-compose-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose-android) → [jetpack-compose-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose-android)
- [compose-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-desktop) → [jetpack-compose-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose-desktop)
- [compose-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-web) → [jetpack-compose-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose-web)
- [jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose) (for stuff where it isn't specific to a platform)

Somehow namespacing just makes more sense if it's consistently done from the front.

Comment: Why don't we just have a single [[tag:jetpack-compose]] tag? If the question is specific to a particular platform, you'd also add the tag for that platform (e.g., [[tag:android]]).

Comment: If we're doing namespacing though, it's probably worth highlighting that compose-desktop and compose-web actually are [compose-multiplatform] (possibly [jetbrains-compose-multiplatform] (https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/; same source repo). Admittedly, the imports [still overlap with Jetpack](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/01d0203284bc355bdb61634288eac1a97ae9c351/examples/todoapp/common/compose-ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/example/todo/common/ui/ShortcutHandler.kt#L3-L5), but this doesn't seem to apply to other platform's unique code

Comment: For instance, [the web-specific code](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/01d0203284bc355bdb61634288eac1a97ae9c351/examples/todoapp/web/src/jsMain/kotlin/example/todo/web/Components.kt#L4-L29) for one of the examples uses a whole bunch of imports unique to web components. That's arguably enough to warrant [jetbrains-compose-multiplatform] and [android-jetpack-compose], though I'm not sure what's best to do in the cases where there's actual overlap, such as in the core code where all the imports are identical to jetpack's imports

Comment: Tagging on a per-product basis seems more reasonable than globbing all of them into one, misleading tag that seems to imply compose-desktop and compose-web are both authored and released by Google as a part of Jetpack, when it really isn't. This also defends [android-jetpack-compose] as a future proof way to protect against other products named jetpack, that happen to include a function or class or whatever named "compose"

Comment: We also have [compose-multiplatform] already, though it's trivial to rename it if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure jeckpack compose cares about anything but android. [Their whole product page is about android/java](https://www.jetpackcompose.net/jetpack-compose-introduction) development.

Comment: Fair, I hadn't even noticed that [compose-multiplatform] also existed, so that's another one to add into the mix.

Comment: @Braiam well, that linked page is just one guy's random blog on the subject, and I assume that person only cares about Android, but you're kind of right in some regards because the [actual product page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) is also under the Android site. I don't know whether this is something that would change as the desktop and web targets get more mature or what the plans are there. (I guess Google and JetBrains would have to get together and agree to merge the site or something if it was going to happen.)